# 2-dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, zero

Assume you are given an int variable named `nPositive` and a 2-dimensional array of ints  that has been created and assigned to `a2d`. Write some statements that compute the number of all the elements in the entire 2-dimensional array that are greater than zero and assign the value to `nPositive`.

Code:

```
for(int i=0; i<a2d.length; i++){
    int nPositive;
    for(int j=0; j<a2d[a2d.length-1].length; j++) {
        if(a2d[i][j] > 0) {
            nPositive = a2d[i][j];
        } 
    }
}
```

It has a compilation error. Why?

Comment: what is the compilation error? as someone else stated, be more detailed with your question.

Comment: I think you mean `a2d[i].length` for your inner loop counter. Also the number of elements in the array of arrays is *not* the value of the individual elements.

Comment: More Hints:
     ⇒     Are you sure you want to use: -
     ⇒     You might want to use a number other than 1

Comment: these are all i've got  :(

Comment: Is that what you are calling compiling errors? What is telling you that?

Comment: I looked on google for these error messages and it seems a website named Codelab, on which one can turn homeworks into gives that kind of error message. You should compile your code with an actual compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The iiner cycle is incorrect:

```
for(int j=0; j<a2d[i].length; j++){
```

Comment: if i do it this way, the program says" You seem to have an error in compilation" :(

Comment: What kind of worthless compiler gives you a message consisting of "You seem to have an error in compilation"?!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `nPositive`.

```
// make nPositive a global variable
int nPositive = 0;

for(int i=0; i<a2d.length; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<a2d[a2d.length-1].length; j++) {
    if(a2d[i][j] > 0) {
        nPositive += a2d[i][j]; // add the value into nPositive as you go through the array
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: primitives can't be null. He did not also need to assign it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and find that,There is no any compilation error in your code...

```
 for(int j=0; j<a2d[a2d.length-1].length; j++){//
```

let the length is a2d[10][10]

on statement `a2d[a2d.length-1].length ,is equal a2d[10-1].length ,is equal a2d[9].length=>10`

your algo is working fine for me ,i found no any error 
**here's my test code**

```
    public class A2dTest {

  public static void main(String[] arr) {
            int[][] a2d = new int[10][10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    a2d[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1000000;// all positives
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < a2d.length; i++) {
                int nPositive = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < a2d[a2d.length - 1].length; j++) {
                    if (a2d[i][j] > 0) {
                        nPositive = a2d[i][j];
                         System.out.println("nPositive=" + nPositive);
                    }}
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is one of the questions on codeLab. You just need to properly initialize nPositive at 0 and increment it for every positive integer. That's all they're looking for involving the output. So your code needs to be:

```
    nPositive = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a2d.length; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a2d[i].length; j++) 
    {
        if (a2d[i][j] > 0) 
        {
            nPositive++;
        }
    }
}
```